# Typescript : Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable'

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a problem with Observable type, any idea?

```
import { PostModel } from '../model/postModel';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

class DataStore {

    private posts: PostModel[]  = [];

    private postListSubject = new Subject();

    public postsList$: Observable<PostModel[]> = this.postListSubject.asObservable();

    initializeLessonsList(newPost: PostModel[]) {
        this.posts = _.cloneDeep(newPost);
        this.broadcast();
    }

    addLesson(newPost: PostModel) {
        this.posts.push(_.cloneDeep(newPost));
        this.broadcast();
    }

    broadcast() {
        this.postListSubject.next(_.cloneDeep(this.posts));
    }
}

export const store = new DataStore();
```

on the line `public postsList$: Observable<PostModel[]> = this.postListSubject.asObservable();` I am getting this error

> [ts] Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type
>   'Observable'.   Type '{}' is not assignable to type
>   'PostModel[]'.
>       Property 'includes' is missing in type '{}'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add type information to your `postListSubject` declaration to allow the TypeScript compiler to infer the correct type of the `Observable` that is returned by `Subject.asObservable()`:

```
private postListSubject = new Subject<PostModel[]>();
```

Answer (score 0):

this

```
const s = new Subject();
const o: Observable<Model[]> = s.asObservable();
```

results in the error you have.

Change it to this

```
const s = new Subject<Model[]>();
const o: Observable<Model[]> = s.asObservable();
```

and all is fine!

so...

in your code, change this:

```
private postListSubject = new Subject();
```

to this:

```
private postListSubject = new Subject<PostModel[]>();
```

If you don't provide a type, the type will default to `{}`! This is like an object with no properties, and indeed cannot be mapped to the `PostModel[]` type that you use.

have a nice day!